# What is Boto3 Inspector v2 list_findings' nextToken initial value?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using boto3 Python to list findings from Inspector v2, using the list_findings() method inside a loop, according to [AWS Boto3 Inspector2 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/inspector2.html#Inspector2.Client.list_findings) I have to set the value of this parameter to null for the first request to a list action but keep getting error in all these cases for variable next_token:

- **nextToken = None:** botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
  Invalid type for parameter nextToken, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
- **nextToken = 'null':** botocore.errorfactory.ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListFindings operation: Pagination token exception in operation 'ListFindings': invalid payload wrapping schema -24855
- **nextToken = empty string:** An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ListFindings operation: Pagination token exception in operation 'ListFindings': invalid payload (no encryption schema version)

here is my code:

```
import boto3
inspector = boto3.client("inspector2")
next_token = "" # I change the value of this variable 
while True:
    response = inspector.list_findings(
            filterCriteria={
                'findingStatus': [
                    {
                        'comparison': 'EQUALS',
                        'value': 'ACTIVE'
                    },
                ],
                'findingType': [
                    {
                        'comparison': 'EQUALS',
                        'value': 'PACKAGE_VULNERABILITY'
                    },
                ],
            },
        nextToken=next_token
    )
    next_token= response.get("nextToken") 
    
    # Some Code Here 
    
    if next_token == None:
        break
```

I am confused about what should the value of nextToken be for the first request?

Comment: For the first request, do _not_ provide a `nextToken` value.

Comment: @Marcin I am trying to generate some kind of Slack Notification relying on findings from AWS Inspector 2, but afraid that I might miss something when I get a token returned, I want to have the initial value for the nextToken.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein how do I do that? do you mean making a request before the loop?

Comment: Normally, you simply wouldn't specify a `nextToken` on the first call. It _might_ work as an empty string -- did you try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use [paginate](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/inspector2.html#Inspector2.Paginator.ListAccountPermissions.paginate) as explained in [AWS docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html#creating-paginators):

```
# Create a client
inspector = boto3.client("inspector2")

# Create a reusable Paginator
paginator = inspector.get_paginator('list_findings')

# Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(filterCriteria={
                'findingStatus': [
                    {
                        'comparison': 'EQUALS',
                        'value': 'ACTIVE'
                    },
                ],
                'findingType': [
                    {
                        'comparison': 'EQUALS',
                        'value': 'PACKAGE_VULNERABILITY'
                    },
                ],
            })

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page)
```

Comment: This one helped me, this would have been a better answer if it mentions more information about pagination, I am new to this term, and this article helped me https://www.eternalsoftsolutions.com/blog/what-is-aws-cli-pagination/